# when I update the table column error occured

Tags: php, sql

This is my SQL  update query . but problem is that when I update title of table but error occurred when in the title inverted single comma exist? because in update query inverted comma use for php variable.  error like :

```
[ UPDATE zen_meta_tags_products_description SET metatags_title = 'What experiences are being evoked in Brancusi's Bird' Where products_id=412 ]
```

query is given below:

```
  while(!$ab->EOF)
  { 
    echo  $count. " ". $p_id= $ab->fields['products_id'];
     echo $p_name= $ab->fields['products_name'];
 echo " <br>";
 echo   "meta title : ".$m_name= $ab->fields['metatags_title'];
echo " <br>";
 $db->Execute("  UPDATE zen_meta_tags_products_description SET metatags_title = '$p_name' Where products_id=$p_id ");
$count++;
    $ab->MoveNext();

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is with the single quote or apostrophe in the name.  This needs to be escaped.  In PHP, the easiest way to escape a string is mysql_real_escape_string().  I just noticed that this will be deprecated.  In order to escape a string, a \ needs to be placed before the character.  For example:

```
UPDATE zen_meta_tags_products_description SET metatags_title = 'What experiences are being evoked in Brancusi\'s Bird' Where products_id=412
```

You can change your sql command to:

$db->Execute("  UPDATE zen_meta_tags_products_description SET metatags_title = '".mysql_real_escape_string($p_name)."' Where products_id=$p_id ");

and that should work until mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated.

Comment: thanks yr great yr..... realy happy from you. it is real;y big issue for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this

```
$db->Execute("UPDATE zen_meta_tags_products_description SET metatags_title = '".$p_name."' Where products_id='".$p_id."' ");
```

I suggest you to use `rawurlencode` to avoid this kind of errors. So then query will be

```
$db->Execute("UPDATE zen_meta_tags_products_description SET metatags_title = '".rawurlencode($p_name)."' Where products_id='".$p_id."' ");
```

Remember that, if you are using `rawurlencode`, For viewing the title. You should use `rawurldecode` to decode the string

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use ADOdb library.
In that case you can use [qstr](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#qstr) function.